# Information on Isaiah 6: 1-6

Tags: isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Is what is described in [Isaiah 6:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.6.1)-6 a vision, or is the prophet actually inside the temple of Jerusalem? Does he say he sees G-d on the throne and the doorposts that tremble?

Comment: Both Rashi and the Radak indicate that this was a vision.

Comment: Any time it says someone "saw" G-d it means a vision.

Comment: The vision is of G-d’s name that is referenced in the sentences. G-d and his name(s) are one.

Comment: The vision of Hashem is undoubtedly a vision, but whether or not Yeshayahu was in the Temple at the time or not is a good question. Not being a kohen (per Jewish tradition he was part of the Davidic royal family) he would not have been allowed to stand in the Hechal itself, but he might have stood in the courtyard outside of the building.

Comment: Don't some commentaries connect this with Amos' dating something by "the earthquake"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the Rambam in his [Guide for the Perplexed](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.6.1?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Guide%20for%20the%20Perplexed&lang2=en) concerning whether it was a vision or not:

> THE sublime and great subject which Ezekiel by prophetic impulse began to teach us in the description of the Mercabah, is exactly the same which Isaiah taught us in general outlines, because he did not require all the detail. Isaiah says, “I saw the Lord sitting upon a throne, high and lifted up, and his train filled the temple. Above it stood seraphims,” etc. (Isa. 6:1 seq.). Our Sages have already stated all this clearly, and called our attention to it. For they say that the vision of Ezekiel is the same as that of Isaiah, and illustrate their view by the following simile:—Two men saw the king riding, the one a townsman, the other a countryman. The former, seeing that his neighbours know well how the king rides, simply tells them that he saw the king; but the villager, wishing to tell his friends things which they do not know, relates in detail how the king was riding, describes his followers, and the officers who execute his order and command. This remark is a most useful hint; it is contained in the following passage (Ḥagigah, 13 b): “Isaiah saw all that has been seen by Ezekiel: Isaiah is like a townsman that sees the king, Ezekiel like a countryman that sees the king.”

I found a [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.6.1?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en), that seems to explain that when it says that G-d sits on His throne, this is to mean the kingship of G-d and that He rules, e.g. "He sits on His throne". (my own interpretation of this Malbim) As the posuk states "upon a throne, high and lifted up".

Because of the well-known principle, [“The language of the Torah is like the language of man.”](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.1.26?lang=en&p2=Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_1.46.7&lang2=en&w2=all&lang3=en) - the Rambam explains, G-d is described in Ezekiel for example, with physical features. However, G-d has no form, no body etc.. The only reason it says that, is, according to the Rambam, so that we can understand it better.

As to your question whether Isaiah could be in the Holy Temple itself during this vision. This could be possible, but, as per Harel13's comment, I do not think it was in the Hechal itself.

Please see the commentary of the [Rabbeinu Bahya on Bamidbar 15:38](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bamidbar.15.38.11?ven=Torah_Commentary_by_Rabbi_Bachya_ben_Asher,_trans._Eliyahu_Munk,_1998.&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> Isaiah prophesied and had visions at a time when the Temple was still standing. This is why the chayot had more wings than when Ezekiel prophesied at a time when the Temple had already been destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

"In his vision, Isaiah saw the throne of G-d. (This is an anthropomorphism; of course, G-d has no literal body or physical throne.)" - Rabbi Jack Abramowitz , https://outorah.org/p/3873/

Rabbi Tovia Singer explains Isaiah's ability to see G-d in [Yeshayahu 6] although a vision like seeing a rainbow [Yechezkel 1:28] is for a humanitarian purpose: **"The reason why a prophet is given permission to speak and criticize Israel is to make the jewish people better"** (44:15-44.22) https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bLFw2Tb2x88

The visions of "Glory" (Kevod) in [Yeshayahu 6], [Tehillim 18], [Yechezkel 10] are contemplative moments of inspiration for Ivrit prophets.

Unlike the idiomatic "head in the clouds" state, neviim are cognizant when respectfully envisioning HaShem robed in dark clouds carried by malakim whose thunderous wings cause them to tremble at the instant when the Spirit of El Shaddai gives insight about conducting tasks to improve life on earth.

Comment: In the current state, aside from not being particularly clear, this answer is more of an opinion. Sources to support points are always encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

It's a vision and a lesson and a rebuke, and per @Harel13 comment he's not inside the temple (though it's an interesting question whether he was in the courtyard etc.) and of course no one sees God per se, and regarding the pillars that probably refers to the Midot of Netzach and Hod.

In Isa. 6:1 it's written ADN"Y so he's saying he perceived the Middah/Sefirah of Malkhut, but then in v. 3 he hears Kadosh (3x) indicating Tiferet so in v. 5 he says ''Oy-li ki hidmeiti'' - I was mistaken and was actually perceiving that Middah of Tiferet (but אוי =17 = TOB good, ''li'' - to me; that is, no I was actually right) -  but no, the reason he thought he was mistaken was because he's "dwelling among people of unclean lips." This is according to the Arizal and brought in Ben Yehodada on Yebamot 49b.

https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.6.5?lang=bi&p2=Yevamot.49b.10&lang2=bi&w2=Ben%20Yehoyada&lang3=en

כָּל הַנְּבִיאִים נִסְתַּכְּלוּ בְּאַסְפַּקְלַרְיָא שֶׁאֵינָהּ מְאִירָה, מֹשֶׁה רַבֵּנוּ נִסְתַּכֵּל בְּאַסְפַּקְלַרְיָא הַמְּאִירָה. הנה לפי דברי רבינו האר"י ז"ל אספקלריא המאירה הוא בחינת שם הוי־ה שהוא סוד התפארת הנקרא בשם שמש **ושאינה מאירה הוא בחינת שם אדנ־י שהוא סוד המלכות הנקראת בשם לבנה. וכתב רבינו ז"ל דישעיה הנביא ע"ה השיג במלכות דבריאה ולזה אמר 'וָאֶרְאֶה אֶת אֲדֹנָ־י' (ישעיה ו, א) שהיא המלכות ואחר כך בשמעו מה שהיו אומרים 'קָדוֹשׁ קָדוֹשׁ קָדוֹשׁ הֳ' צְבָקוֹת' (ישעיה ו, ג) שהוא התפארת חשב כי את התפארת ראה ואמר 'אוֹי לִי כִי נִדְמֵיתִי' שאני חשבתי שראיתי במלכות אך עתה ידעתי 'כִּי אֶת הַמֶּלֶךְ הֳ' צְבָקוֹת רָאוּ עֵינָי' (ישעיה ו, ה) והסיבה שטעיתי היא מפני כִּי בְּתוֹךְ עַם טְמֵא שְׂפָתַיִם אָנֹכִי יוֹשֵׁב, 'וַיָּעָף אֵלַי אֶחָד מִן הַשְּׂרָפִים' (ישעיה ו, ו) ואמר לו כך הוא האמת שלא ראית אלא רק את המלכות ומה שחשבת אחר כך שטעית אין זה אמת כי לא טעית עד כאן דבריו זלה"ה [זכרונו לחיי העולם הבא]**.

---

See also Shaarei Orah, Shaar 3 and 4, end, for more complete elucidation - and that whoever attains unto being mitkaven these things according to the yichud of the Ten Sefirot during saying Kedushah - "his portion is Life, and the words of his mouth are to the Ratzon (accepted), and he's Ben Olam Haba."

https://www.sefaria.org/Shaarei_Orah%2C_Third_and_Fourth_Gates%2C_Seventh_and_Eight_Sefirah.23?vhe=Shaarei_Orah,_grimoar&lang=bi&with=About&lang2=en

ואחר שהודענוך כללים אלו במידת י"י צבאות, ראוי לנו לבאר עכשיו סוד החתימה על דרך הקדושה, בסוד 'קדוש קדוש קדוש י"י צבאות מלא כל הארץ כבודו'. הנה אמר הנביא עליו השלום: ואראה את אדני יושב על כסא רם ונשא (ישעיהו ו, א), הנה באמת כי השם הנקרא אדנ"י, שהוא סוד הספירה האחרונה, הוא יושב על כיסא וארבע חיות הקודש נושאות אותו. 'שרפים עומדים ממעל לו', כלומר לשם אדנ"י, שהם שני שרפים בעלי שש כנפים המשמשים לי"י צבאות שהוא סוד ג' ספירות תחתונות של ו' של שם יהו"ה, כמו שכבר כתבנו למעלה, ומכוח ו' יבא להם שש כנפים. 'וקרא זה אל זה ואמר קדוש קדוש קדוש': קדוש ראשון הוא סוד המשכת אצילות הקודש מן הכתר עליון עד ספירת גדולה; קדוש שני, סוד המשכת אצילות הקודש מן החכמה עד ספירת גבורה; קדוש שלישי הוא המשכת אצילות הקודש מן הבינ"ה ועד ספירת תפאר"ת. הרי לך שש ספירות אמורות, שלוש כנגד שלוש, שלוש משפיעות הקדושה על שלוש. מה כתיב בתריה? יהו"ה צבאות, הרי שלוש ספירות שלמטה מהם אמורות, שהם נצ"ח והו"ד יסו"ד; יבא להן השפע מאת גדול"ה גבור"ה תפאר"ת, מאת כת"ר חכמ"ה בינ"ה. הרי תשע ספירות נאמרות. ובמה הן מריקות ברכותיהן ומשפיעות כוחותיהן? בספירה העשירית, הנקראת אדנ"י, הנקרא ארץ. וזהו סוד שאמר בסוף הפסוק מלא כל הארץ כבודו' (ישעיהו ו, ד). הנה הודענוך בסוד זה הפסוק בעניין הקדושה התאחדות עשרת הספירות ודרך אצילות השפע משלוש עליונות שהן כת"ר חכמ"ה בינ"ה, לשלוש אמצעיות שהן גדול"ה גבור"ה תפאר"ת, לשלוש תחתונות שהן נצ"ח והו"ד יסו"ד. והנה כל שפע אלו תשע ספירות מריק בספירה עשירית שהיא אדנ"י ונקראת אר"ץ, וזהו שאמר 'מלא כל הארץ כבודו'. **ודע והאמן כי העונה קדושה ומכוון בדרך זה בייחוד הי' ספירות, חלקו לחיים ואמרי פיו לרצון והוא בן העולם הבא.** ועניין שנתייחדה הקדושה בפסוק זה כסדר זה, זהו פירושו: קדוש, כתר, קדוש שני, חכמ"ה, קדוש שלישי, בינ"ה. מה כתיב בתריה? צבאות. וסוד צבאו"ת כולל נצ"ח הו"ד יסו"ד. מה כתיב בתריה? מלא כל הארץ כבודו, שהוא סוד הספירה העשירית הנקראת אדנ"י, שהיא ארץ החיים, שהיא אור החיים. וכן הוא אומר: אתהלך לפני ה' בארצות החיים (תהלים קטז, ז). ופסוק אחר אומר: להתהלך לפני אלהים באור החיים (שם נו, יד). ופירוש שני הפסוקים הללו: 'והארץ האירה מכבודו'. וכן הוא אומר קדוש קדוש קדוש יהו"ה צבאות מלא כל הארץ כבודו. וכמדומה לנו כי די שרמזנו לך עכשיו בעניין זה, והשם ברחמיו יורנו דרך האמת אמן: